# ImportError: cannot import name 'dnn_logit_fn_builder' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn'

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

Using `jupyter notebook` in a `conda env` leads me to that error when importing `tensorflow_hub`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dnn_logit_fn_builder' from partially initialized module 
'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn' (most likely due to a circular import) 
(C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py)
```

My env was created installing pandas, tensorflow-hub, numpy, tensorflow and python=3.8.5.

For more details:

```
tensorflow                2.3.0           
tensorflow-base           2.3.0           
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0              conda-forge
tensorflow-hub            0.12.0             conda-forge
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case (Windows 10, Python 3.8, its own shell) I also encountered this problem. Then, individually importing the problematic line resolved issue. In other words, I wrote

```
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
```

then i imported

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

everything was fine.

Comment: Interesting.  Since the question itself doesn't provide any code, can you describe what you did that replicated the problem...in other words, the BEFORE?  I'm curious, and I think that this answer will have more value if you show that.

Comment: It is complicated. Previously it had worked without any error, but last day it produced the same error as in the question with "import tensorflow_hub" function. Since the error text hinted at circular import, I checked Traceback lines and tried importing them one by one. Only importing this sufficed. 
When I tried to replicate the error today, again it imported seamlessly :)

Answer (score 1):

Works with Tensorflow 2.6.0 with little change in the api name as `tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.dnn_logit_fn_builder`

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.dnn_logit_fn_builder
```